# Custom WPF ListBox using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

First step : a simple ListBox

```
<ListBox Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,0,0,0" Name="myList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="287">
```

with that code :

```
myList.Items.Add("toto");
```

Ok, it's working fine.

Second step : I want to have two columns for each row.

So I tried that

```
<ListBoxItem Name="my_item">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Name="my_item_id"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="my_item_name"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ListBoxItem>
```

But in my code ?

I tried

```
my_item_id = "1234";
my_item_name = "toto";
myList.Items.Add(my_item);
```

But it's not working ...  I suppose I'm doing wrong but then how to make it working ?

Thanks.

Comment: In case you want the columns to be resizable and have a more Grid-Like look and feel think about using a ListView instead of ListBox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You should assign an [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) to the `ListBox` which [binds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) on the items. e.g.

   ```xml
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
               <!-- ... -->
   ```
2. You add items which have those properties, e.g. [anonymous objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

   ```
   myList.Items.Add(new { Id = "Lorem", ... });
   ```

See also: [Data Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)